# Flutter - How to use same Bloc to query specific entry in Firestore with calendar?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, bloc

I'm currently trying to build a Flutter app using BloC and have encountered some problems i hope you guys could help me with! I'm new to BloC in general so please be understanding.

I have created a BloC for adding, deleting, updating and listing data from firestore, which works fine. What i do need some help with is what i need to do in order to make my code query only entries created on the same day as i pick in my calendar widget with the pickedDate variable i got.

I want the ListView to generate tasks to its correct day, so for example if 2020-05-19 has 2 tasks, it should appear two tasks when picking that day in the calendar. I don't really know what i need to change or do on the calendar in order to achieve this since i still think BloC is a bit confusing.

Do i have to make a seperate bloc for the Calendar or is it okey to use the same bloc that handles my tasks?

Maybe it's just something small i forget to do but i feel completely lost at the moment. Currently i fetch all the firestore entries to a ListView just to see if it works, like this:

```
Widget _buildCalendarListView(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<TasksBloc, TasksState>(builder: (context, state) {
      if (state is TasksLoading) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      if (state is TasksLoaded) {
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: state.tasks.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              var task = state.tasks[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(task.description),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      } else {
        return Text('No tasks');
      }
    });
  }
```

And here is my Calendar widget:

```
Widget _buildTableCalendar() {
return TableCalendar(
  onDaySelected: (DateTime day, List events) {
    pickedDate = day;
  },
  calendarController: _calendarController,
  startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
  calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
    selectedColor: Colors.blue,
    todayColor: Colors.blue[200],
  ),
);
```

}

and my BloC for the Tasks where i pass datetime right now:

```
class TasksBloc extends Bloc<TasksEvent, TasksState> {
  final TaskRepository _taskRepository;
  StreamSubscription _taskSubscription;

  TasksBloc({@required TaskRepository taskRepository})
      : assert(taskRepository != null),
        _taskRepository = taskRepository;

  @override
  TasksState get initialState => TasksLoading();

  @override
  Stream<TasksState> mapEventToState(
    TasksEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is LoadTasks) {
      yield* _mapLoadTasksToState(DateTime.now());
    } else if (event is AddTask) {
      yield* _mapAddTaskToState(event);
    } else if (event is UpdateTask) {
      yield* _mapUpdateTaskToState(event);
    } else if (event is DeleteTask) {
      yield* _mapDeleteTaskToState(event);
    } else if (event is TasksUpdated) {
      yield* _mapTaskUpdatedToState(event);
    }
  }

  Stream<TasksState> _mapLoadTasksToState(DateTime queryDate) async* {
    _taskSubscription?.cancel();
    _taskSubscription = _taskRepository.tasks(DateTime.now()).listen((tasks) {
      add(
        TasksUpdated(tasks),
      );
    });
  }

  Stream<TasksState> _mapAddTaskToState(AddTask event) async* {
    _taskRepository.addTask(event.task);
  }

  Stream<TasksState> _mapUpdateTaskToState(UpdateTask event) async* {
    _taskRepository.updateTask(event.updatedTask);
  }

  Stream<TasksState> _mapDeleteTaskToState(DeleteTask event) async* {
    _taskRepository.deleteTask(event.task);
  }

  Stream<TasksState> _mapTaskUpdatedToState(TasksUpdated event) async* {
    yield TasksLoaded(event.tasks);
  }
}
```

and here's the repository i created for firestore:

```
    class FirebaseTaskRepository extends TaskRepository {
  final taskCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('tasks');

  @override
  Future<void> addTask(Task task) {
    return taskCollection.add(task.toEntity().toDocument());
  }

  @override
  Future<void> deleteTask(Task task) {
    return taskCollection.document(task.id).delete();
  }

  /* @override
  Stream<List<Task>> tasks() {
    return taskCollection.snapshots().map((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.documents
          .map((doc) => Task.fromEntity(TaskEntity.fromJson(doc.data)))
          .toList();
    });
  } */

  @override
  Stream<List<Task>> tasks(DateTime queryDate) {
    return taskCollection
        .where('date', isGreaterThan: queryDate)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.documents
          .map((doc) => Task.fromEntity(TaskEntity.fromJson(doc.data)))
          .toList();
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> updateTask(Task update) {
    return taskCollection
        .document(update.id)
        .updateData(update.toEntity().toDocument());
  }
}
```

And also my Main.dart, where i use MultiBlocProvider which im not sure if i use correctly and there for i can't achieve what i want? :

```
 void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  BlocSupervisor.delegate = MyBlocDelegate();
  final UserRepository userRepository = UserRepository();

  runApp(
    BlocProvider(
      create: (context) =>
          AuthenticationBloc(userRepository: userRepository)..add(AppStarted()),
      child: App(userRepository: userRepository),
    ),
  );
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  final UserRepository _userRepository;

  App({Key key, @required UserRepository userRepository})
      : assert(userRepository != null),
        _userRepository = userRepository,
        super(key: key);

/*  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is Unauthenticated) {
            return LoginScreen(userRepository: _userRepository);
          }

          if (state is Authenticated) {
            return HomePage(name: state.displayName);
          }
          return SplashScreen();
        },
      ),
    );
  } */

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<TasksBloc>(
          create: (context) {
            return TasksBloc(
              taskRepository: FirebaseTaskRepository(),
            )..add(LoadTasks());
          },
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        routes: {
          '/': (context) {
            return BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is Unauthenticated) {
                  return LoginScreen(userRepository: _userRepository);
                }

                if (state is Authenticated) {
                  return HomePage(name: state.displayName);
                }
                return SplashScreen();
              },
            );
          },
          '/addTask': (context) {
            return NewTaskScreen(
              onSave: (task, description, date) {
                BlocProvider.of<TasksBloc>(context).add(
                  AddTask(
                    Task(task, description: description, date: date),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
          '/calendarScreen': (context) {
            return CalendarScreen();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No one able to point me in the right direction ?